# Using 'send' in passive voice

Tags: phrases

> You are sent this e-mail because...

Is this correctly worded or does it sound weird? I ask because I think I've seen similar wordings, such as "you are being sent X because Y", but I'm not at all sure what I wrote is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks perfectly correct to me.

First; because

> [when an active sentence with an indirect object is recast in the
>   passive, the indirect object can take on the role of subject in the
>   passive sentence.](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/passive.htm)
>
> **Active**    Professor Villa gave Jorge an A.
>
> **Passive**   An A was given to Jorge by Professor Villa.
>
> **Passive**   Jorge was given an A.

Then, because

> [The Simple Present Tense is used to indicate a habitual action.](http://www.english-for-students.com/Present-Tense.html)

So, one can imagine that the company staff send (this kind of) emails every day, and it just so happens (or not) that you are the recipient of this particular one.

Answer (score 0):

There's an error with tenses, try using 'were' in place of 'are':

> "You were sent this e-mail because..."

Comment: That's not an error. The different tense means a different thing.

Comment: @red Yes, but the different tense would then mean something that is not applicable to this situation. My wording is certainly less "weird" sounding.

Comment: Depends on the letter-writing style involved. You can use tense with the "present" at the reader's time, or at the writer's (earlier) time. This is not a matter of grammar. Grammar just tells you there are two tenses, not which one to use in a letter.

Comment: @Lewis: You can't know which wording is applicable to this situation because we don't know what "this situation" *is*. If "this email" refers to the very email the sentence is part of, then the present tense is clearly preferrable. Just like you'd use "I'm writing you this to..." and not "I was writing you this to...". It is irrelevant that at the time the reader is reading the email, you are no longer writing it. You are writing it not from their standpoint, but from yours. Likewise for sending. From the sender's perspective, the recipient *is* and not *was* being sent the email.